# When did Mainda and Dvivida drink Amrita with the permission of Brahma?

Tags: ramayana, brahma, hanuman, balarama, amrita

Mainda and Dvivida are the valiant lieutenants in the army of Vānara. They are the sons of Ashwini Kumaras. Hanuman describes the plight of Lanka to his fellow vānaras and praises every Vānara including Angada, Jambavan, Neela etc., When it comes to Mainda and divida, Hanuman praises them as [follows](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/sundara/sarga59/sundara_59_frame.htm).

> अश्विपुत्रौ महाभागावेतौ प्लवगसत्तमौ |
>   एतयोः प्रतियोद्धारम् न पश्यामि रणाजिरे ||  ५-५९-१७
>
> aśviputrau mahābhāgāvetau plavagasattamau |
>   etayoḥ pratiyoddhāram na paśyāmi raṇājire || 5-59-17
>
> "These two illustrious sons of Ashvini Kumaras, Mainda and Dvivida are the foremost among the monkeys. In the battle-field, I do not find anyone who can fight against these two monkeys."
>
> पितामहवरोत्सेकात्परमम् दर्पमास्थितौ |
>   **अमृतप्राशनावेतौ** सर्ववानरसत्तमौ || ५-५९-१८
>
> pitāmahavarotsekātparamam darpamāsthitau |
>   **amṛtaprāśanāvetau** sarvavānarasattamau || 5-59-18
>
> **Proud of having received boons from Brahma the creator and their grandfather** and abiding in a supreme haughtiness, these two foremost among all the monkeys **live on Amrita the nectar**.

In yuddhakanda too, they were said as drinking amrita.

> यौ तौ पश्यसि तिष्ठन्तौ कुमारौ देव रूपिणौ |
>     मैन्दः च द्विविदः च उभौ ताभ्याम् न अस्ति समो युधि || 6-28-6
>     ब्रह्मणा समनुज्ञाताव् अमृत प्राशिनाव् उभौ |
>     आशंसेते युधा लंकाम् एतौ मर्दितुम् ओजसा || 6-28-7
>
> The two who stand there, who have the same resemblance and have the appearance of celestials, are Mainda and Dvivida. None can equal them in combat. **These two, who ate ambrosion on due authorization by Brahma**, are hopefully of destroying Lanka by their power.

- What boons did Mainda and Dvivida receive from Brahma?
- When did Mainda and Dvivida drink nectar?
- How was Dvivida [got killed](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/what-happened-to-the-vanara-sena-after-the-ramayana/2100#2100) by Balarāma despite of drinking nectar?

Comment: I think Balarama was able to kill Dvivida as Balarama was Adi Sesha who was inturn Vishnu. It also looks like Balarama was aware of his divinity.

Comment: @The Destroyer I do not understand. Drinking the nectar means immortality and what does that has to do with Vishnu? How was Balaram able to kill him while he was immortal?

Answer (score 1):

A Partial answer.

In [Vishnu Purana](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp153.htm), it was mentioned that Naraka had a friend of exceeding prowess in the monkey named Dwivida, a great Asura.  Balarama eliminates that asura Dwivida.

> The great Asura, the foe of the friends of the gods, Naraka, had a
> friend of exceeding prowess in the monkey named Dwivida, who was
> animated by implacable hostility against the deities, and vowed to
> revenge on the whole of them the destruction of Naraka by Krishńa, at
> the instigation of the king of the celestials, by preventing
> sacrifices, and effecting the annihilation of the mortal sphere.
>
> Blinded by ignorance, he accordingly interrupted all religious rites,
> subverted all righteous observances, and occasioned the death of
> living beings: he set fire to the forests, to villages, and to towns:
> sometimes he overwhelmed cities and hamlets with falling rocks; or
> lifting up mountains in the waters, he cast them into the ocean: then
> taking his place amidst the deep, he agitated the waves, until the
> foaming sea rose above its confines, and swept away the villages and
> cities situated upon its shores.
>
> Dwivida also, who could assume what
> shape he would, enlarged his bulk to an immense size, and rolling and
> tumbling and trampling amidst the corn fields, he crushed and spoiled
> the harvests. The whole world, disordered by this iniquitous monkey,
> was deprived of sacred study and religious rites, and was greatly
> afflicted.
>
> On one occasion Halá yudha was drinking in the groves of Raivata,
> along with the illustrious Revatí and other beautiful females; and the
> distinguished Yadu, in whose praises songs were sung, and who was
> preeminent amidst graceful and sportive women, resembled Kuvera, the
> god of riches, in his palace. Whilst thus engaged, the monkey Dwivida
> came there, and stealing the ploughshare and the club of Baladeva,
> grinned at and mocked him, and laughed at the women, and threw over
> and broke the cups filled with wine. Balaráma, becoming angry at this,
> threatened the monkey; but the latter disregarded his menaces, and
> made a chattering noise: on which Bala, starting up, seized his club
> in wrath;  and the monkey laid hold of a large rock, which he burled
> at the hero.
>
> Bala casting his club at it, as it neared him, broke it into a
> thousand fragments, which, together with the club, fell upon the
> ground. Beholding the club prostrate, the monkey sprang over it, and
> struck the Yádava violently on the breast with his paws. **Bala replied
> with a blow of his fist upon the forehead of Dwivida**, which felled
> him, vomiting blood, and lifeless, **to the earth.**

So it was not Dwivida of Ramayana, but an asura in the form of monkey with a same name, who was eliminated by Balarama.

Comment: Valmiki Ramayana is silent on the issue of circumstances under which and when did the brothers got boons from Brahma and drank Amrita.@Sarvabhouma

Comment: How do we know that Dvivida from Ramayana is not the Dvivida who was killed by Balarama? The main part of your claim that both are different is not confirmed. The story you have quoted in the answer is already linked in the question. I linked from Bhagavatam. Jiva Goswami who wrote a commentary on Bhagavata says Dvivida who was killed by Balarama and one from Ramayana are one and the same. I am actually interested in when Mainda and Dvivida drank nectar. Since no details are found in Ramayana, I asked in hope this might be referenced somewhere else. This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Yes,  that is why I had stated that it is a partial answer.  Coming to the authenticity of Dwivida,  in link to  the site that I had provided did not say so!  Please check.

Comment: You were quoting Bhagavata Purana,  whereas I had quoted Vishnu Purana.  So narration might be different @ Sarvabhouma

Comment: The story and narration both are same. It is implied that Dvivida is also the same.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: The crucial aspect is  it was stated in Vishnu Purana that Dwivida was an Asura in the form of a monkey, whereas Ramayana did not state Dwivida was an Asura

Comment: Both the narrations from Bhagavata and Vishnu Purana doesn't say they are different vanaras. There is no supportive statement that they are different vanaras. Whereas there are commentaries on Bhagavata which state Divivida from Ramayana and Mahabharata time are same. In Vishnu Purana he is not an Asura like Ravana but asuric due to his character. He is vanara in Vishnu Purana also.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering the 3rd question on how Dvivida was killed by Balarama.

After Lakshmana had killed Indrajit, he was affected by a fever as he had killed a Brahmin (his grandfather was the Brahmin Vishravas). Sugreeva’s minister Dvivida wrote a mantra and put it infront of Lakshmana. Immediately, his fever was gone. An elated Lakshmana granted Dvivida a boon. The monkey says he would like to obtain a death at Lakshmana’s hands, which was granted [Ref: Kalki Purana 3.13.10-19].

After Bhaumasura’s (Narakasura's) death, his friend Dvivida followed God Krishna to Dwarka. He was a giant monkey who used to be a minister in the court of Sugreeva in Kishkindha. Dvivida was upset with the death of his friend. He attacked Dwarka and wreaked havoc. He started throwing big trees and rocks at Balarama, who ended up dispatching him to Yama-loka, the abode of the dead. Peace returned to the prosperous city of Dwarka [Ref: Bhagavata Purana 10.67].

Ref: 'Essence of the Fifth Veda' by Gaurang Damani page 107