# Has any human ever consumed Amrit?

Tags: human, amrita

I want to understand if the effects of Amrit when drunk by a human has ever been mentioned anywhere in the hindu mythology. Has there ever been a human who has consumed it ?

Comment: Do Vanaras count? They did.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma: While I would like an answer strictly from the human viewpoint, who are you talking about?

Comment: I am talking about [Mainda and Dvivida](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17530/5212).

Comment: Amrit is naturally generated on cranium after some time of deep spiritual practice. And yogis drink it by one specific mudra with tongue, avoiding amrit to go down towards stomach and being digested. When drinking by tongue, amrit goes back to blood and make good health. But when someone makes very good deep sadhan, amrit goes abundant and without mudra also we can take it back to blood. For example with nam jap (full of devotion). You can read yogic literature

Comment: Why do you ask this question? Do you want to become immortal?