# When was Shiva a disciple of sage Angiras?

Tags: shiva, puranas, vishnu-purana

One of the most famous wars between the gods and the Asuras (demons) was the Tarakamaya war.  The war was started when Chandra the moon god kidnapped Tara, wife of Brihaspati guru of the gods.  (Brihaspati is often just called Guru, and he's the god of the planet Jupiter.). To rescue their guru's wife, the gods fought a great war against Chandra, and the Asuras took Chandra's side because of Sukracharya's personal animus towards Brihaspati.  In the end Chandra gave back Tara, but not before she became pregnant with his son, Budha god of the planet Mercury.

In any case, the army of the gods was led by Shiva, who fought on the side of Brihaspati because of his loyaly to Brihaspati's father Angiras, as [described](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp098.htm) in the Vishnu Purana:

> In vain Vrihaspati sought to recover his bride; in vain Brahmá commanded, and the holy sages remonstrated; Soma [Chandra] refused to relinquish her. Uśanas [Sukracharya], out of enmity to Vrihaspati, took part with Soma. **Rudra [Shiva], who had studied under Angiras, the father of Vrihaspati**, befriended his fellow-student. In consequence of Uśanas, their preceptor, joining Soma, Jambha, Kujambha, and all the Daityas, Dánavas, and other foes of the gods, came also to his assistance; whilst Indra and all the gods were the allies of Vrihaspati.

My question is, what is this story of Shiva studying under the sage Angiras?

Now Angiras was one of the mind-born sons of Brahma, so he's certainly old enough.  But does anyone know any other scriptures that describe Shiva as a student of Angiras?  Are there any other details known about this?

EDIT: I just found out that [this chapter](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/9/14) of the Srimad Bhagavatam also describes Shiva as a disciple of the sage Angiras:

> Because of enmity between Bṛhaspati and Śukra, Śukra took the side of the moon-god and was joined by the demons. But Lord Śiva, because of affection for the son of his spiritual master, joined the side of Bṛhaspati and was accompanied by all the ghosts and hobgoblins.

Comment: As per Shiv-Puran, there is originally a supreme God called Sadashiv and he created Bramha Ji and Vishnu Ji and then he himself incarnated in his poorna roop as 'Rudra' (which most of us know as Shiv Ji today) from Bramha Ji's eyebrows, so may be we are talking about this form of 'Rudra' who was born may be later than Angiras and had some study under him.

Comment: My question isn't about Shiva vs Sadashiva. (Obviously we're talking about Brahma's son Shiva here, not some formless entity Brahman.) My question is about what the story is of Shiva studying under Angiras. Whether you call him Shiva or Rudra, it still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Dear @keshav bro angiras is not spritual master of lord shiva nor lord rudra lord rudra was yes in the side of devas but bramha purana doesn't discribe this thing. See yourself it is discribed in vaishnava puranas only niether kurma nor vayu just like shiva scriptures gives story of sudarshana chakra given by shiva but not else puranas.

Comment: @Fiercelord First of all, I don't think there's a distinction between Shiva and Rudra.  And second of all, I think the Pramana of the Vishnu Purana is good enough.  As for the reason for differences between Vaishnava and Shaiva Puranas, that's due to Sattvika, Rajasika, and Tamasa Puranas.

Comment: Added another reference from Brahmavaivarta Purana (considered as one of the 6 Brahma purana and by few also a Rajasa purana).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan VP (4.13) says अंगिरसश्च सकाशादुपलब्धविद्यो भगवान्रुद्रो बृहस्पतेः सहाय्यमकरोत्. It only speaks of Rudra and Angiras and does not mention the word "Shiva". Prabhupad, Sridhar or anyone might hold on to the cherished belief that Rudra is Shiva, however, while referring to literature, textualism cannot be disregarded. Your esteemed self seems to be an intellectual personality, therefore, I hope that you can recognize the advantage of creating a coherent and consistent approach, wherein the ordinary and plain meaning of the text is at least stated correctly.

Comment: 1st of all there are 3 types of shava avatar 1st is lord shiva who we also called sada shiva he is formless. Than there is shankar/shambhoo or mahadeva who has form and family and next is the partial incarnations 11 Rudras who have different name in different Puranas and are the sons of sage Kashyap and mata aditi. So this may be one of the 11 rudras who studied under sage angiras as almost all adityas, etc studied under him.

Answer (score 3):

According to Sri Ishwara Gita, chapter 6.:

> यो वामदेवोऽङ्गिरसः शिष्यो रुद्रगणाग्रणीः ।
> रक्षको योगिनां नित्यं वर्त्ततेऽसौ मदाज्ञया ॥ ६.२७॥
>
> Meaning: - Best among the eleven rudras of Lord Maheshwara– that ‘Vamadeva’ who is disciple of rshi Angira protect the yogins on my (Lord Shiva's) instruction.

So, it's 11 Rudras who are the deciples of Sage Angira not Lord Shiva himself. Even Adityas (which consist of vishnu, an avatar not vaikuntha lord vishnu), Vasus (which consist of pavaka aka agni), etc also studied under him. As he is the divine guru and father even the guru of dev guru Brihaspati himself.