# Do all astika schools of thought in Hinduism believe that itihaas(Ramayan and Mahabharata) are really historic and not mythology?

Tags: scripture, philosophy

There are many schools of thought in Hinduism

So, do all astika schools of thought believe that Ramayan and Mahabharata are real history and not mythology?

Comment: Vedanta believes they are real. Purva Mimamsa believes they are mythological. I'm not sure about the other 4 astika schools.

Comment: @Ikshvaku which Vedanta there are 3 different Vedantas. Advaita, dvaita, vishishta advita Vedanta (sorry if there is any mistake)

Comment: @DarkKnight There are many schools of vedanta. Advaita (Shankara), Vishishtadvaita (Ramanujacharya), Dvaita (Madhavacharya), Shuddhadvaita (Vallabhacharya), Achintya Bhedabheda (Chaitanya Mahaprabhu), Dvaita advaita (Nimbarkacharya). There are subsects like ISKCON etc. All vedanta schools believe that ithihasas are real.

Comment: @GIRIBLR okay, thanks didn't know about this.

Comment: @DarkKnight ALL Vedanta sects believe that the Smritis contain historical facts.

Comment: @DarkKnight This will help: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/16998/11726

Comment: @Ikshvaku it a question. No one has answered it

Comment: Ramayana mahabharata are called ithihasas. Ithihasas literal meaning itself is history. Mythology is a tag given from british. Wrong literal word translation. They are historical culture of India.

Comment: There are 120 kings that ruled between mahabharata and invasions to India which was erased by britishers from Indian history.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti that's the question, how many or which school of thought believe that Ramayan and Mahabharata are real history and not mythology

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti and also which believe it is mythology

Comment: Bro why are you giving your 120 valuable points for this? Please understand-not all schools need to accept them. Itihas were written to teach Bhakti Jnana and Karma indirectly to everyone with a bit of Samkya and Yoga also. Even Mimasarkas quoted it - like Kumarila Bhatta. Sorry if I offended you - I never wanted to. I was sad you are giving your valubale points

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru well, I I want to know that which school believe them as real and which school as mythology.

Comment: @sv okay I have edited it