# Is there a relation between Gadhi, the Kaushik incarnation of Indra and Ahalya?

Tags: indra, rishi, shatapatha-brahmana, vishwamitra, chandravansh

Indra, in the Subramanaya invocation is referred to as both Kaushik, one who calls him Gautama as well as the lover of Ahalya ([Shatpatha Brahman relevant chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe26/sbe2614.htm)). **While the part about Gautam and Ahalya seems straightforward since Indra impersonated the rishi, how does Kaushik fit in?**

> 3:3:4:18. 'Come, O Indra!' Indra is the deity of the sacrifice: therefore he says, 'Come, O Indra!' 'Come, O lord of the bay steeds! Ram of Medhâtithi! Wife of Vrishanasva! Bestriding buffalo! Lover of Ahalyâ!' Thereby he wishes him joy in those affairs of his.
>
> 3:3:4:19. 'O Kausika, Brahman, thou who callest thee Gautama.' Just so has this (formula) been devised in these days by Âruni, to wit, 'thou who callest thee Gautama:' he may say it, if he choose, and if he does not choose, he need not attend to it . 'In so and so many days, to the Soma-feast,' (stating) in how many days from hence the pressing is to be.

According to Sâyana's commentary, the king Kusika desired to have a son equal to Indra, so the latter was born as Kusika's son Gâthin (Gâdhin). This is corroborated by the [RV Verse 1.10.11](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01010.htm) as well:

> 11 O Indra, Son of Kuśika, drink our libation with delight.
> Prolong our life anew, and cause the seer to win a thousand gifts.

**Does it imply in any way that Indra, as Gadhi, was married to Ahalya?**

Comment: Hello there! [This question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12180/what-is-the-story-of-indra-relearning-the-vedas-from-vishwamitra) is about the same avatara of Indra but about a different story related to him. It may be helpful (?).

Comment: Hi Surya.. yes it is about the same Avatar but I couldnt find what I was looking for. Was Indra as Kaushik married to Ahalya? Some accounts mention Shadvimsa Brahmana suggests Kaushik and Ahalya were married that's why my query.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Why are you adding chandravansh and other tags for questions? Some of tags are not needed for those questions.

Comment: Really? I thought it would make it easier to find interesting questions about these dynasties through the tags otherwise people have no inkling about the genealogies of these prominent personalities except maybe Krishna and Rama

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Although your intention is good, but these tags looks like redundant. For example, there's no need to add add Chandra-vamsha tag for questions of Krishna and pandavas. But we can add Surya-vamsa tag if question is explicitly about Surya vamsa kings or something about Surya Vamsas. There are also rules for tag naming. We need to provide - between words and words should be in Sanskrit if they are of Indian languages or Sanskrit.

Comment: Also, remember to [create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site.](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)