# Gods and respective Chakra

Tags: gods, chakras

Which Chakra is associated with which Hindu God?

Please use the current Hindu Gods, and not only the Vedic ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottom 6 chakras are related to Maa Shakti and the 7th upper chakra is related to Lord Shiva. When Kundalini awakens Shakti rises from mooldhara chakra through Sushuma naadi and then she pierces 3 knots or granthis viz., Brahma Granthi near muldhara chakra (anus), Vishnu Granthi near anagata chakra (heart) and Rudra Granthi near ajna chakra (the junction of eyebrows) and thus reached Sahasrara Chakra and meet Lord Shiva there. And the union of Shiv-Shakti gives the yogi immortality or moksha. Let me cite some verses regarding the yoga and pranayama.:

> “deha.n shivaalayaM prokta.n siddhida.n sarvadehinaam.h |” (Yogashikha Upanishad 1:168)
>
> “For all those who have a body, their body is the temple of Shiva. It gives them siddhi (fulfillment of yogic goal viz. salvation)”.

> “mUlAdhArAdiShaTchakra.n shaktisthAnamudIritam.h |
> kaNThAdupari mUrdhAnta.n shAMbhava.n sthAnamuchyate |” (Varaha Upanishad 5:53)
>
> “The six Chakras beginning with Muladhara are said to be the seat of Sakti (Goddess). From the neck to the top of the head is said to be the seat of Sambhu (Shiva)”.

> “nADInAmAshrayaH piNDo nADyaH prANasya chAshrayaH |
> jIvasya nilayaH prANo jIvo ha.nsasya chAshrayaH |” (Varaha Upanishad 5:54)
>
> “To the Nadis, the body is the support (or vehicle); to Prana, the Nadis are the support; to Jiva, Prana is the dwelling place; to Hamsa, Jiva is the support”.

> “ha.nsaH shakteradhiShThAna.n charAcharamida.n jagat.h |
> nirvikalpaH prasannAtmA prANAyA.n samabhyaset.h |” (Varaha Upanishad 5:55)
>
> “To Sakti, Hamsa is the seat and the locomotive and fixed universe. Being without distraction and of a calm mind, one should practise Pranayama”.

> “kumbhena kumbhayetkumbha.n tadantasthaH para.n shivam.h |
> punarAsphAlayedadya susthira.n kaNThamudrayA |” (Varaha Upanishad 5:60)
>
> “It is only through Kumbhaka that Kumbhaka should be firmly mastered. Within it is Parama-Shiva. That (Vayu) which is non-motionless should be shaken again through Kantha-Mudra (throat-posture)”.

> “prakR^ityashhTakaruupa.n cha sthaana.n gachchhati kuNDalii |
> kroDiikR^itya shiva.n yaati kroDiikR^itya viliiyate |” (YogaKundalini Upanishad 1:74)
>
> “Kundalini assumes the eight forms of Prakriti (matter) and attains Shiva by encircling him and dissolves itself in Shiva”.

> “rudragranthi.n cha bhittvaiva kamalaani bhinatti shhaT.h |
> sahasrakamale shaktiH shivena saha modate
> saivaavasthaa paraa j~neyaa saiva nirvR^itikaariNii iti |” (YogaKundalini Upanishad 1:86)
>
> “Then it pierces Rudragranthi, after that, (all) the six lotuses (or plexuses). Then Sakti is happy with Shiva in Sahasrara Kamala (1000 lotuses seat or pineal gland). This should be known as the highest Avastha (state) and it alone is the giver of final beatitude (Kaivalya / Sayujya Moksham)”.

I hope this clarifies your queries.

Comment: Very beautiful. Thank You for taking the time to answer.

Comment: U are most welcome. ..

Answer (score 5):

I'm giving this answer basis three sources:

1. Lalitā-Sahasranāma.
2. The Serpent Power by Arthur Avalon (Sir John Woodroffe).
3. Garuda Purana

---

### 1. Lalitāsahasranāmam:

A good amount of detail is found in the [lalitāsahasranāma](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/lalita.html): Verses 98 to 110

I'm compiling a table for a bird's eye view:

| Sr. No. | Chakra Name | Location | Presiding Deity (Yogini) | Complexion of the deity | Body Parts Controlled | Food | Corresponding Verses | English Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | **Mūlādhāracakra** (मूलाधारचक्र) | In between the Anus & Genitila | **Sākinyambā** | Smoke-Colored | Bones | Mudgaudana (मुद्गौदना) | [Verse 106](https://archive.org/details/pli.kerala.rare.25882/page/n229/mode/1up?view=theater) | Sacral Plexus |
| 2. | **Svādhiṣṭhānacakra** (स्वाधिष्ठानचक्र) | At the root of Genitila | **Kākinīyambā** | Yellow-Colored | Fat | Mead (मधु) | [Verse 104-105](https://archive.org/details/pli.kerala.rare.25882/page/n228/mode/1up?view=theater) | Postatic Plexus |
| 3. | **Maṇipūracakra** (मणिपूरचक्र) | Navel | **Lākinyambā** | Red-Colored | Flesh | Rice with Jaggery (गुडान्न) | [Verse 102-103](https://archive.org/details/pli.kerala.rare.25882/page/n227/mode/1up?view=theater) | Solar Plexus |
| 4. | **Anāhatachakra** (अनाहतचक्र) | Heart | **Rākiṇyambā** | Black-colored | Blood | Greasy Food (स्निग्धौदन) | [Verse 100-101](https://archive.org/details/pli.kerala.rare.25882/page/n225/mode/1up?view=theater) | Cardiac Plexus |
| 5. | **Viśuddhachakra** ( विशुद्धचक्र) | Throat | **Ḍākinīyambā** | Rosy-Complexioned | Skin | Milk-food (पायसान्न) | [Verse 98-99](https://archive.org/details/pli.kerala.rare.25882/page/n224/mode/1up?view=theater) | Throat Chakra |
| 6. | **Ājñācakra** (आज्ञाचक्र) | Forehead, in between the eyebrows | **Hākinīambā** | White | Marrow | Saffron-Flavored (हरिद्रान्नैक-रसिका) | [Verse 107-108](https://archive.org/details/pli.kerala.rare.25882/page/n229/mode/1up?view=theater) | Cavernous Plexus |
| 7. | **Sahasrāra** (सहस्रार) | Brahmarandhra | **Yākinyambā** | All-Colors | Semen | All foods (सर्वौदन-प्रीतचित्ता) | [Verse 109-110](https://archive.org/details/pli.kerala.rare.25882/page/n230/mode/1up?view=theater) | The Crown Chakra |

<sup>The English Translation is based on Bhaskararya's Commentary</sup>

---

### 2. Serpent Power:

Arthur Avalon dwells deep in detail on this subject encompassing several chapters.
He has compiled a table in his book. I'm tabulating the relevant columns.

| Sr. No. | Chakra Name | Presiding Deity | Deity's Vāhana | Tattvas Ruled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Mūlādhāra | Brahmā | Haṃsa | Earth |
| 2. | Svādhiṣṭhāna | Viṣṇu | Garuḍa | Water |
| 3. | Maṇipūra | Rudra | Vṛṣabha | Fire |
| 4. | Anāhata | Īśa | - | Air |
| 5. | Viśuddha | Sadāśiva | - | Ether |
| 6. | Ājñā | Śambhu | - | Mind |
| 7. | Sahasrāra | - | - |  |

<sup>The detailed compiled table by Arthur Avalon in his book can be found in pages 141 & 142, [from here](https://archive.org/details/TheSerpentPowerByArthurAvalon/page/n161/mode/2up).</sup>

---

### 3. Garuḍa Purāṇa

> [Chapter XV](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-garuda-purana-2/d/doc63656.html#note-t-40189), Garuḍa Purāṇa (abridged)
>
> 72. & 73. Mūlādhāra, Swādhishthāna, Maṇipūraka, Anāhatam, Viśuddhi and
>     also Ājñā,--are spoken of as the six chakras.
>
> One should meditate in order upon the chakras, at the root of the
> generative organ; in the region of the pelvis; in the navel; in the
> heart; in the throat; between the eyebrows; at the top of the head.
>
> 74. & 75. The mūlādhāra is four-petalled and resplendent, with letters
>     from va to sa; the Svādhiṣṭhāna resembles the sun, is six-petalled,
>     and has the letters from ba to la; the Maṇipūraka is red in colour and
>     has ten petals, from da to pha; the Anāhata is twelve-petalled, from
>     ka to tḥa, and is golden-coloured;
>
> The viśuddhi lotus is sixteen-petalled, with the vowels, and has the
> light of the moon; the Mātra[25] lotus is two-petalled, has the
> letters ha and kṣa, and is red in colour; the one at the top of the
> head is the most resplendent, this lotus has a thousand petals, and is
> the seat of truth and bliss, ever auspicious, light-possessing and
> eternal.
>
> 76. One should meditate, in order, in the chakras, on Gaṇeṣa, on Vidhi, on Viṣhṇu, on Śiva, on Jīva, on Guru, and on Parambrahmaṇ,
>     all-pervading.

Therefore,

| Chakra Name | Presiding Deity |
| --- | --- |
| Mūlādhāra | Gaṇeṣa |
| Svādhiṣṭhāna | Vidhi (Brahmā) |
| Maṇipūra | Viṣhṇu |
| Anāhata | Śiva |
| Viśuddha | Jīva |
| Ājñā | Guru |
| Sahasrāra | Parambrahmaṇ<sup>**1**</sup> |

<sup>Footnote 1: As per Śivapurāṇa  [Verse 10.4.(7 & 8)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226616.html#note-t-89146), that is  the Nirguṇa Sadāśiva.</sup>

---

Also, an alternate deity arrangement can be found in the Śiva-Purāṇa  too, as follows:

> Śiva Purāṇa  [Verse 1.13.(40 & 41)](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225558.html)
>
> मूलाधारं समारभ्य द्वादशांतस्थितांस्तथा ।
> विद्येशब्रह्मविष्ण्वीशजीवात्मपरमेश्वरान् ॥ ४० ॥ ब्रह्मबुद्ध्या तदैक्यं
> च सोहं भावनया जपेत् । तानेव ब्रह्मरंध्रादौ कायाद्बाह्ये च भावयेत् ॥ ४१
> ॥
>
> > 40. & 41. He shall meditate on Vidyeśa, Brahmā, Viṣṇu, Īśa, Jīvātman and Parameśvara stationed in the twelve esoteric centre of the body
> >     from Mūlādhāra (basic support) to the Brahmarandhra (the mystical
> >     aperture at the crown of the head), as identical with Brahman with the
> >     conception of Soham (I am He) and continue the Japa. He shall then
> >     meditate on them as stationed outside the body as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I honestly thought that it was GANESH who actually preside the Mūlādhāra one. But anyway, thanks for this input.

Comment: @LuckyPashu ... I have added what you were looking for. Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 3):

I found the below description from a Srimad Bhagavata [lecture](http://vishwanandini.com/fullupanyasa.php?serialnumber=VNU706)  by Sri Vishnudasa Nagendracharya. It is in Kannada language so I documented the information here as a table.

Unfortunately the discussion here is focused on the spiritual lotuses rather than the chakras. The number of such lotuses are more than the number of popular 7 chakras. Hence there is a confusion in mapping the lotuses to chakras. I could not resolve it so I have put the notes as they are in the below table. I have supplemented the information from a [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/Divya-DarshaNa-712003448810299/photos/bhaghavat-roopa-chintanekataka-upanishads-mantra-which-is-chanted-during-madhyaa/2401724129838214)

| **Chakra** | **Location** | **Color** | **Number of petals** | **Deity of lotus** | **Deities in petals** | **Mandala** | **Lakshmi roopa** | **Vishnu roopa** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Moolaadhaara | Anus | red | 4 | **Swayambhu Manu** | Guru, Budha, Chandra, Shani | Vahni | Krti | Pradyumna |
| Manipura | Navel | red | 6 | **Ganapathi** | Shanmahishis – Jambavathi, Kalindi, Bhadra, Mitravinda, Neela, Lakshana | Vayu | Shanti | Aniruddha (black) |
| Anaahata? | Heart | sunrise | 8 |  | Ashta vasus and Digdevatas– Indra (east), Agni (south east), Yama (south), Nirriti (south west), Varuna (west), Pravaha Vayu (north west), Kubera (north), Rudra (north east) | Surya – 12 (masa adhipathis), Agni | Maaya | Vasudeva |
| Anaahata? | Talavya | pearl | 12 | **Shiva, Parvati** | Dwadasha Adityas | 6 angle Vayu | Shaanti | Aniruddha (black) |
| Vishuddha? | Indrayoni (special) |  | 16 | **Narayana** |  | 16 tithi devatas |  |  |
| Vishuddha? | Indrayoni |  | 2 | **Shesha, Varuni** | Brahma, Vayu | Circular Chandra | Jayaa | Sankarshana (yellow) |
| Ajna | Bhroo madhya | white | 4 | **Garuda, Sauparni** |  | Circular Chandra – 4 petals | Lakshmi | Narayana (red) |
| Sahasrara? | Shiras |  | 1000 | **Brahma, Vayu, 200 Rujus, 14 loka adhipathis** | 1000 Vishnu roopas from sahasranama in each petal |  | Maaya | Vasudeva |
| Sahasrara? | Above Shiras |  | 12 |  |  | dwadasha adityas | Maaya | Vasudeva |

**General description of the lotuses**

- A form of Lord Vishnu and Goddess Lakshmi who are sitting on Lord Shesha
- Shesha himself is poised on a lotus with a mandala in the centre sometimes with another set of upper petals with a central "mandala"
- The base lotus with characteristic number of petals; There is a "niyamaka" devata(s) for the lotus who himself/herself/themselves form the petal. I have considered this as the required "Gods" in question.

**References**

As quoted by the speaker in the lecture

- "Padaratnavali" by [Vijayadhvaja teertha](https://www.sumadhwaseva.com/yatigalu/udupi-mutts/vijayadwaja-tirtharu/) which is a commentary on Madhwacharya's Bhagavata commentary
- "TatvakaNika" by [Sheshachandrikacharya](https://madhwayati.blogspot.com/2019/04/raghunatha-teertharu-1755-tirumakoodalu.html) which is a commentary on "Tantrasara sangraha" by Madhwacharya
- "Tatvasaara" by Sheshachandrikacharya which is a commentary on "Brihati Sahasra"
- [Vijaya Dasa's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vijaya_Dasa) "Upasana bhaga suLadis"

Comment: Does the acarya quote any scriptures, from where he might be explaining?

Comment: He uses "Padaratnavali" by Vijayadhvaja teertha (15th century pontiff of Pejawar mutt) which is a commentary on Madhwacharya's Bhagavata commentary, He also refers certain aspects from Madhwacharya's "Tantrasara sangraha" and "Brahma sootra bhashya". But much of details are from Jagannatha Dasa's "Harikathamrutasara". I am collecting more accurate information. Will update the post accordingly.

Comment: I have edited the whole answer. Hopefully it makes more sense now

Comment: I upvoted your answer, for providing a fresh purely-Vaishnavite take on the Chakras, but, honestly speaking I'm not able to make much sense of it. How come, there are repetitions of Chakras! And also, what's with the question mark after Chakras?

Comment: Some padmas have a subset of characteristics of more than one chakra. In the Facebook link mentioned in the answer mapping of chakras to Padmas are given but they are not agreeing on some characteristics. Hence I left a question mark. It requires more study on the references mentioned to fully resolve. If I manage to get the missing pieces I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Sri Narad Maha Puran mentions the seven major chakras and the deities who govern them.

In the First Part of the Narad Puran inside Chapter 65

> एवं ध्यात्वार्पयेद्धीमान्वह्न्यर्केषु विभागशः ।। मूलाधारे
> वादिसांतबीजयुक्ते चतुर्दले ।। ६५-८१ ।। बंधूकाभे स्वशक्त्या तु
> सहितापास्वगाय च ।। पाशांकुशसुधापात्रमोदकोल्लासपाणये ।। ६५-८२ ।। षट्शतं
> तु गणेशाय वागधीशाय चार्पयेत् ।। स्वाधिष्ठाने विद्रुमाभे
> वादिलांतार्णसंयुते ।। ६५-८३ ।। वामांगशक्तियुक्ताय विद्याधिपतये तथा ।।
> स्रुवाक्षमालालसितबाहवे पद्मजन्मने ।। ६५-८४ ।। ब्रह्मणे षट्सहस्रं तु
> हंसारूढाय चार्पयेत् ।। विद्युल्लसितमेघाभे डादिफांतार्णपत्रके ।। ६५-८५
> ।। मणिपूरे शंखचक्रगदापंकजधारिणे ।। सश्रिये षट्सहस्रं च विष्णवे
> विनिवेदयेत् ।। ६५-८६ ।। अनाहतेऽर्कपत्रे च कादिठांतार्णसंयुते ।। शुक्ले
> शूलाभयवरसधाकलशधारिणे ।। ६५-८७ ।। वामांगे शक्तियुक्ताय विद्याधिपतये
> सुधीः ।। वृषारूढाय रुद्राय षट्सहस्रं निवेदयेत् ।। ६५-८८ ।। विशुद्धे
> षोडशदले स्वराढ्ये शुक्लवर्णके ।। महाज्योतिप्रकाशायेन्द्रियाधिपतये ततः
> ।। ६५-८९ ।। सहस्रमर्पयेत्प्राणशक्त्या युक्तेश्चराय च ।। आज्ञाचक्रे
> हक्षयुक्ते द्विदिलेऽब्जे सहस्रकम् ।। ६५-९० ।। सदाशिवाय गुरवे
> पराशक्तियुताय वै ।। सहस्रारे महापद्मे नादबिन्दुद्वयान्विते ।। ६५-९१ ।।
> विलसन्मातृकावर्णे वराभयकराय च ।। प्ररमाद्ये च गुरवे सहस्रं विनिवेदयेत्
> ।। ६५-९२ ।।
>
> You can read the full English translation from here -
> https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.21516/page/n33/mode/2up?view=theater
>
> I'm attaching screenshot of Hindi interpretation by Gita Press also for everyone's benefit
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

The summary as the translator interpret in the his footnote is as follows-

> **The verses 81 - 91 give the method of Prana-agnihotra and show how the breaths are to be offered to different deities located in the plexuses along the path of Sushumna. The first 600 are to be offered to Ganesha (riding an Elephant along with Vag-devi) located in the Muladhara. Next comes Svadhisthana, where Brahma (sitting on a swan with devi Saraswati) is located. The six thousand are to be offered to him. In the Maipura region to Vishnu (holding conch, discus, mace and lotus, accompanied with Lakshmi mata) another six thousands are to be offered. To Rudra (riding a bull along with wife Gauri) who is in the Anahata, another six thousands are to be offered. In the Vishuddha chakra is Ishvara (accompanied by prana-shakti). Next, to Sadashiva (accompanied by Parashakti) in the Agya/Ajna region one thousand are offered and lastly in the Sahasarara Chakra where the Nada and the Bindu (dedicated to the Guru) are in equilibrium, the last thousand breaths are to be offered.**

So -

Muladhara = Ganesh

Svadhishthana = Brahmaa

Manipura = Vishnu

Anahata = Rudra

Vishuddha = Ishvar

Ajna = SadaaShiv

Sahasrara = Ones' Guru.