# Did Hanuman and Krishna ever met with each other?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, krishna, hanuman

We know that Hanuman is a great devotee and follower of Lord Rama in Treta Yuga.

But my doubt is, did he meet Krishna?

Is it explicitly mentioned anywhere in Vyasa's Mahabharat or some other Hindu text that Hanuman and Krishna met each other? If true, then what exactly happened during their meeting?

Comment: He does meet Krishna and stays inside the flag of Arjuna during war but i am not sure i context of Vyasa Mahabaratha.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yeah, as I discuss here, the Bengali version of the Mahabharata tells the story of Hanuman meeting Krishna and Arjuna: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2100/36 But I'm not sure whether that story has any scriptural basis.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan as suspected

Comment: @AnkitSharma You may be interested in the fact that according to the Adi Parva chapter quoted in my question here, the ape flag was already on Arjuna's chariot when he got it: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3101/36 Perhaps the ape was the emblem of one of the gods who previously used the chariot.

Comment: Arjuna challenges Hanuman to see who's bridge is stronger, then Krishna shatters arrogance of both, and later krishnanjaneya yuddha,  hanuman chases garuda, wrecks Dwaraka, then krishna shows his Rama form.

Answer (score 1):

## `Did Hanuman and Krishna ever meet with each other?`

#### Yes, they did meet once as per the Ānanda Rāmāyaṇa.

As I discuss in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/50479/17833), this episode occurs in the **Sarga Eighteenth of the Manohara kāṇḍa of the Ānanda Rāmāyaṇa**.

The basic premise of the story is to elucidate on the 'origin of Arjuna's Monkey-bannered flag', and thus why Arjuna is also known as Kapi-dhvaja.

This meeting occurs between Arjuna, Hanumāna, and Kṛṣna, in the Rāmeśvaram
in the Dvāpara-yuga before the Mahābhārata war.

Here's a small Sanskrit excerpt from the [18th Sarga](https://archive.org/details/HindiBookAnandRamayan/page/n767/mode/2up?view=theater), which describe the meeting:-

> #### Sarga Eighteen, Manohara kāṇḍa, Ānanda Rāmāyaṇa
>
> चक्रं ययौ यथास्थानं श्रीकृष्णस्याज्ञया तदा । सागरेण स्वकल्लोलः शरसेत
> विलोपितः ॥४१॥ तदाऽर्जुनो गर्वहीनो मेने कृष्णेन जीवितः ।
> कृष्णस्तदाऽर्जुनं प्राह त्वया रामेण स्पर्द्धितम् ।।४२।। हनूमता
> धनुर्विद्या तबातोऽत्र मृषा कृता । यत्प्रतापादिति गिरा त्वयाऽपि
> वायुनन्दन । ४३|| रामेण स्पर्धितं यस्मात्तस्मादर्जुन संजितः । अतः परं
> वीतगर्वस्त्वं मां मज निरन्तरम् ॥४४॥ इत्युक्त्वा मारुतिं
> पृष्ट्वाऽर्जुनेन तत्पुरं ययो । अतः कपिध्वजश्चति जनैरर्जुन ईर्यते ॥४५।।
>
> > 41. Thus as per the order of Śrī Kṛṣṇa the Chakra (Sudarśana-chakra) stopped supporting the Arjuna's 'arrow-made bridge', following which even the bridge collapsed back into the sea.
>
> > 42. And thus, Arjuna's ego was annihilated, and Arjuna, therefore, realized how Śrī Kṛṣṇa saved Arjuna's life (by intervening in the bet between him and Hanumān ji).
>
> > 43. **Śrī Kṛṣṇa thus explained, to Arjuna that since he in his ego dared to compare himself with Śrī Rāma, therefore Hanumāna voided his dhanur-vidyā (archery-skills). Similarly, he explained to Hanumāna that since Hanumāna boasted about helping Śrī Rāma - thus he was defeated by Arjuna (in his second attempt).**
>
> > 44. & 45. **And thus, losing, wager to Arjuna (with Kṛṣna's apt intervention though), Hanumāna occupied Arjuna's flag, and thus Arjuna came to be known as kapi-dhvaja (Monkey-Bannered).**

The complete story may be read from the linked answer above in [this question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12520/what-scriptures-describe-the-origin-of-arjunas-monkey-flag/50479#50479)

Answer (score -2):

It is doubtful if Sri Krishna and Sri Hanuman had ever met, as per Mahabharata.

[Varuna gave Arjuna](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01228.htm) the great bow Gaandiva and a Chariot, ***whose banner is a large ape,*** before the commencement of Khandava Vana dahana.

> Varuna replied unto Pavaka, saying, 'Well, I am giving them.'
>
> He then gave that wonderful jewel of a bow that was endued with great
> energy. That bow was the enhancer of fame and achievements, and was
> incapable of being injured by any weapon. It was the chief of all
> weapons, and the grinder of them all. And it was the smiter of hostile
> armies and was alone equal to a hundred thousand bows. It was the
> multiplier of kingdoms, and was variegated with excellent colours. It
> was well-adorned, and beautiful to behold, and without a mark of
> weakness or injury anywhere. And it was always worshipped both by the
> celestials and the Gandharvas.
>
> Varuna also gave two inexhaustible quivers, and **he also gave a car**
> furnished with celestial weapons and **whose banner bore a large
> ape**.

Arjuna might have used the same chariot with a large ape on the Flag, during the Mahabharata war also. Arjuna might be using those Gandiva and that Chariot ever since, till [Agni asked him to return to Varuna](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m17/m17001.htm), after the departure of Sri Krishna.

Comment: I don't think this is answering the question. What is the significance of the blockquote and the connection between 'whose banner bore a large ape' and Hanuman?

Comment: @sv.: The prevalent story of Bhima meeting Sri Hanuman and thereafter the latter consenting to be on the flat of Arjuna's chariot during the ensuing Mahabharata war might be an interpolated story.  The ape on the flag of Arjuna's chariot must be of chariot given by Varuna.  Thus , Sri Krishna and Sri Hanuman, had never met, as per Mahabharata .

Comment: If the ape on Arjuna's chariot has no connection to Hanuman, what's the point of quoting how Arjuna acquired the chariot it in your answer?

Comment: Many were under the impression that it was because of Bhima meeting Sri Hanuman, and latter met Sri Krishna. @sv.

Comment: can't it be like ape banner was already there but Bhima requested Hanuman to live in that banner in some form during war?

Comment: My answer is based on Mahabharata.  I am not dwelling in Puranas please. @YDS

Comment: "Many were under the impression that it was because of Bhima meeting Sri Hanuman, and latter met Sri Krishna" - but that's not what the question is asking. For this statement: "It is doubtful if Sri Krishna and Sri Hanuman had ever met, as per Mahabharata" - I don't see any references. Your blockquote has no connection to the first line. This is what is confusing in the answer. Usually we make statements then support them with references. In this case, there is no link between claims and references.