# What is the story of Arjuna becoming depressed when lord Hanuman tested him?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, hanuman, arjuna

I have read somewhere that Arjuna became depressed in the test by lord Hanuman and he got some lessons from the lord. What is the story from the scriptures?

Comment: I'm not aware of any scriptures that describe the story; see my question here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/12520/36

Comment: I think in Mahabharata during the first exile of Arjuna he was at some historic place where he deprecated Lord Rama and Lord Hanuman took monkey shape and challanged him. I may be wrong as I also do not have any proof but I have read on wikipedia.

Comment: Lord Hanuman asks Arjuna to make a bridge of arrows and then Lord Hanuman continually broke it. something like this i read somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the story; I describe it in great detail in my question linked to above.  I'm just not aware of any Hindu scriptures that mention it.

Comment: I think constantly failing made him disappointed.

Comment: I have read the story in Amar Chitra Katha but am yet to come across the same in any scripture.