# Significance of Hanuman in Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, hanuman

I would like to know what is the significance of Hanuman in Mahabharata?

[image]

Comment: For this one need to understand Who is Vayu he is the supporter of the universe as stated in brindharanyaka upanishad. Kirshna says this clearly when appreciating Karnas valour in attacking Arjun ratha making that move 2 step behind.. but where as arjuna infact made the  ratha of karna to go behind and chased also.. when arjun questioned his bias, he says this moving our Ratha 2 step behind is like moving the universe 2 steps behind.. God, and Vayu both present physical whereas Karanas is nothing..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hanuman's Role in Kurukshetra](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12403/hanumans-role-in-kurukshetra)

Comment: All answer are confusing and unfounded @TheLittleNaruto hanuman is Vayu avatar same for bhima if bhima kills duryodhana then its hanuman ir Vayu KILLED duryodhana is also true the answer where given people who thinks hanuman and bhima are not Vayu avatar

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto, it does explain to me the presence of Hanuman in Mahabharata, but why Hanuman??

Comment: Good question and helpful reading suggestion comment; if Asker could expand more on whats meant by 'significance' could be helpful; Askers Comment replying to reading suggestion comment clarifies somewhat, so if Asker could indicate eg if question is more at existential significance / existential implications could be helpful. Thank you :)

Comment: @MH, thank you, I exactly wanted to know that if Hanuman is not shown in Mahabharata, but what is the connection that Pandavas choose Hanuman to be symbolized on their flag during the war.

Answer (score 2):

Mahabharata Vana parva Chapter 141,verse 16 to 19

चमूं विगाह्य शत्रूणां शरशक्तिसमाकुलाम् ।
यदा सिंहरवं वीर करिष्यसि महाबल ॥१६॥

तदाहं बृंहयिष्यामि स्वरवेण रवं तव ।
विजयस्य ध्वजस्थश्च नादान मोक्ष्यामि दारुणान्॥१७॥

शत्रूणां ये प्राणहराः सुखं येन हनिष्यथ ।
एवमाभाष्य हनुमांस्तदा पाण्डवनन्दनम् ॥ १८॥

मार्गमाख्याय भीमाय तत्रैवान्तरधीयत ॥ १९ ॥

"Mahabali Veer Bhimasena, when you will be injured due to the prowess of the enemies arrows, and in distraught when you penetrate amidst the enimies army and shout out the war cry, at that time i will amplify your roar with mine. Other then that sitting in the flag upon Arjuna's Chariot, I will roar with such great intensity that i will seize upon the life air of the enimies, due to which you all will be able to kill them all very easily.
Saying so, Hanuman the giver of happiness to the Pandavas showed the path to Bhimasena and disappeared."

Comment: Thank you!!, I would like to share a story with you, this is an incident when the Pandavas were in exile, and they knew a war is coming. Bhim used to feel very proud of his strength and though he is the most strongest of all. Then Hanuman disguises himself into an old monkey. When Bhim was traveling on a path hanuman kept his tail in between his way. Bhim asked him to get off his way, then Hanuman told him that he is too old to remove his tail all by himself and asked Bhim to remove it, Bhim could not, and when he came to know about Hanuman and requested hanuman to be on their side (Satya).

Comment: The character length is limited, but I hope you can easily understand what I was explaining, now this is a story that my teacher and one of my friends shared with me.

Answer (score 1):

It signifies Adyatma Here Jiva is Arjuna.. is driven in the ratha i.e body. by God Krishna..Under guidance of Vayu that mukhya prana.. When Prana leaves Jiva is dead. That is why after end of the war Krishna asks Arjuna to get down first. Instead of himself. In that incident the Hanuman in flag vanishes after Lord Sri Krishna disembarks the ratha, When God leave the body and so do Prana. God along with prana should be present in body for the body to be alive and do whatever it wants. Here Jiva thinks he is owner of Ratha the body. But actually he is driven by sarathy Krishna. For Human Jiva is soul, Driven by Lord inside the body. guided by Vayu prana thattva.. if prana is missing than god also leaves God along with Prana is important. This substantiated by Tattriyouphanisad Chapter 1 - Siksa Valli

https://www.hinduwebsite.com/taittiriya-upanishad.asp

Namaste Vayo Tavameya prathaksham Brahmasi

Regarding actual reason for hanuman to stay in the chariot is to protect the Ratha. Because hanuman is the only person who is immune to all ashtra and sastra because of his boon from brahma and all parivara devathas.  I believe its salya parva of mahabharat. BG 15.14 verse stating the role prana in the body. Prana which holds the body together

अहं वैश्वानरो भूत्वा प्राणिनां देहमाश्रित: |
प्राणापानसमायुक्त: पचाम्यन्नं चतुर्विधम् || 14||

ahaṁ vaiśhvānaro bhūtvā prāṇināṁ deham āśhritaḥ
prāṇāpāna-samāyuktaḥ pachāmy annaṁ chatur-vidham

https://www.quora.com/What-happened-to-the-horses-of-Arjunas-chariot-after-it-exploded

Sri Bharathiramana Mukhyapranathargatha Sri Krishnsrpnamasthu