# What are the bows of the warriors of the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, weapon, itihasa

I want to know what were the names of the bows of the warriors of the Mahabharata, their abilities and how they got them

Comment: Gandiv, Sarang, Vijaya bows are discussed in https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/14468/12304 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3658/12304 and https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/29715/12304

Comment: 'Shiva Dhanushya' of 'Shree Raam'. But that is not under 'Mahabharata'. That is in 'Ramayana'. Just for info...

Comment: @Vineet Did OP ask of that info ? :D

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto sharing 'related info' in comment (not as an answer) should be okay. If there is any such custom laid down in 'meta' which refrains sharing related info, pl cite it. I will follow the rule. No prob.

Comment: I was referring to the bows of other warriors besides Karna, Krishna or Arjuna

Comment: @GabrielAlexanderGonzalezAgu while commenting, if you wish to address it to a particular member, pl. use @ followed by nickname. Otherwise the concerned user will not be notified.

Comment: Mahabharata has 100's of characters. The list maybe too long. Voting to close as 'too broad'.

Comment: @GabrielAlexanderGonzalezAgu Split the question in to three parts (names, abilities, how they got) and ask as three different questions.

Answer (score 8):

The partial list of names of bows that was mentioned in Mahabharata
 are :

Krishna : **Saranga**

Arjuna : **Gandiva**

Rukmi : **Vijaya**

Siva : **Pinaka**

Yudhishthira : **Mahendra**

Bhimasena : **Vayavya**

Nakula : **Vaishnava**

Sahadeva : **Aswina**

Ghatotkacha : **Paulastya**

Prativindhya, Sutasoma, Srutakarman, Satanika, and Srutasena : **the Raudra, the Agneya, the Kauverya, the Yamya, and the Girisa.**

For detailed explanation, see the following passages from [Mahabharata](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/index.htm).

From [Udyoga Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/index.htm) of Mahabharata, we have the [following](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05159.htm) excerpt

> "Vaisampayana said, '..... And that mighty-armed warrior had obtained
>   also the bow named Vijaya of celestial workmanship, belonging to the
>   great Indra, and which was equal to Gandiva in energy and to also
>   **Sarnga (held by Krishna).** There were three celestial bows owned by the denizens of heaven, viz., Gandiva owned by Varuna, the bow called
>   Vijaya owned by Indra, and that other celestial bow of great energy
>   said to have been owned by Vishnu. This last (Sarnga), capable of
>   striking fear into the hearts of hostile warriors, was held by
>   Krishna. **The bow called Gandiva was obtained by Indra's son
>   (Arjuna)** from Agni on the occasion of the burning of Khandava, while
>   the bow called **Vijaya was obtained from Drona by Rukmi of great
>   energy**.....'

From of [Sabha Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/index.htm)Mahabharata, we have the following [excerpt](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m02/m02045.htm)

> Vaisampayana continued,--".... In thy dream, O king of kings thou wilt
>   behold towards the end of this might the blue throated Bhava, the
>   slayer of Tripura, ever absorbed in meditation, having the bull for
>   his mark, drinking off the human skull, and fierce and terrible, that
>   lord of all creatures, **that god of gods, the husband of Uma,
>   otherwise called Hara and Sarva, and Vrisha, armed with the trident
>   and the bow called Pinaka**, and attired in tiger skin. And thou wilt
>   behold Siva, tall and white as the Kailasa cliff and seated on his
>   bull, gazing unceasingly towards the direction (south) presided over
>   by the king of the Pitris ......'"

From of [Drona Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/index.htm) of Mahabharata, we have the [following](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07023.htm) excerpt

> **In Yudhishthira's hands was the celestial bow called Mahendra; and in
>   the hands of Bhimasena, O king, was the celestial bow called Vayavya.**
>   For the protection of the three worlds Brahman created a bow. That
>   celestial and indestructible bow was held by Phalguni. **The Vaishnava
>   bow was held by Nakula, and the bow called Aswina was held by
>   Sahadeva. That celestial and terrible bow called the Paulastya, was
>   held by Ghatotkacha. The five jewels of bows born by the five sons of
>   Draupadi were the Raudra, the Agneya, the Kauverya, the Yamya, and the
>   Girisa**. That excellent and best of bows, called the Raudra, which
>   Rohini's son (Valadeva) had obtained, the latter gave unto the
>   high-souled son of Subhadra, having been gratified with him.

Comment: I appreciate the efforts taken by you for collecting separate names. +1.