# Did Parashurama ever meet Lord Krishna?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, parashurama

The widely held belief is that it was Parashurama who gave sudarshana chakra to Lord Krishna. However as seen in this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/1991/18974) it was not the case. So my question is  did the two ever meet given that they were contemporaries at time of Mahabharata ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they did meet. As per [Bhagwat Yana Parva - Udyoga Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05083.htm), Lord Krishna was on his way to Hastinapur to attempt reconciliation between Kauravas and Pandavas. On his way,

> **Kesava** of mighty arms met with some Rishis blazing with Brahmic lustre, standing on both sides of the road, And soon alighting from his car, **Janardana** saluted them reverently. And worshipping them duly, he enquired of them

In response to Lord Krishna's enquiry,

> **Jamadagni's son**, the friend of Brahma--that lord of both gods and Asuras,--approached **Govinda** the slayer of Madhu, embraced him.

Furthermore Parashurama also stated that he desires to watch Krishna address kshatriyas, and will again meet him at the Hastinapur conclave.